# How can we have conditional resource values in android?

Tags: android, string, resources

I need to access conditional resource value for string as below:

<resource> 
<string name="str1"> String 1 </string>
....
***if (defaultVariableValue=val_1)***
<string name="resString"> Test Application Key </string>
***else***
<string name="resString"> Live App Key </string>
.....

</resource>

Comment: But, why would Package name change for live or test app?

Comment: handle this condition in .java file

Comment: Why don't you add two strings and put this condition in java code?

Comment: Are you using gradle?

Comment: What I meant to do is, I have 2 API keys that are subjected to user region (say ASIA/REST_OF_WORLD).
In the app, when user selects "ASIA" then the app should read "Test Application Key" ELSE read "Live App Key"

I want it to handle in the resource file instead writing if/else wherever applicable.

Comment: @MidasLefko
Yes I am using gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use product flavors in your build.gradle for your module:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion xx
    buildToolsVersion "xx.x.x"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion xx
        targetSdkVersion xx
        versionCode x
        versionName "xxxxxxxxx"
    }
    productFlavors {

        testing{
            applicationId = "com.example.testing"
            resValue "string", "resString", " Test Application Key "
        }

        live{
            applicationId = "com.example.live"
            resValue "string", "resString", " Live Application Key "
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your code just call `getResources().getString(R.string.resString);` And depending on the build it'll either give you the testing or live key.

Comment: Sounds promising,
With your answer to the question, I would like to know if I can put in a runtime variable at the places **applicationId** by any chance?

That could be the root solution for my specific case

Comment: "com.example.testing" / "com.example.live" - can these values be variable in your solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(getResources().getString(R.string.str1))
   getResources().getString(R.string.resString)
```

Answer (score 0):

@**Swapnil** : I don't know whats your requirement .But You may use **equals() instead =**

```
if (defaultVariableValue.equals(val_1))
{

// Your Staff
 .getResources().getString(R.string.resString);
}
else
{
// Your Staff
.getResources().getString(R.string.yyyyy);
}
```